# What is difference between SvelteKit and sveltejs/template

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Why is that when using `sveltejs/template` to create application doesn't automatically detect the routes I created?

I first tried using `npm create svelte@latest` where I dont have issue creating routes, but after switching to `npx degit sveltejs/template` to create my application, is already a nightmare.

I tried to switch to the later because almost all the guides found on the internet when using global CSS implementation are using`sveltejs/template`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's archived and shouldn't be used](https://github.com/sveltejs/template), I think that is all you really need to know.

> This repo is no longer maintained. Consider using `npm init vite` and selecting the svelte option or — if you want a full-fledged app framework — use SvelteKit, the official application framework for Svelte.

Looking at the packages, it looks like just a basic setup for compiling components via Rollup. No routing or anything else.

Comment: ohh well that's embarrassing. thanks for pointing out.